# Book with parasitic aliens from the 1990s (?)

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

In this book that I'm pretty sure I read in the 1990s, humanity (especially the humans in power) are gradually being controlled by a race of parasitic aliens. The aliens infect humans by boring through the host's soft palate, and infected hosts crave a weird metallic-tasting pudding that satisfies the alien parasite's taste for iron. ETA: I think the author was a woman.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Crossing-Xavier-Storytellers-Book-1-ebook/dp/B01LR60CEE?

Comment: Thanks, but alas, no. I'm pretty sure the author was a woman. (Added to original question.) I'm surprised about the similarities between this and the book I'm looking for, though.